# How to POST a request using data from console.log in the URL

Tags: javascript

I am receiving a response code which I receive as follows:

```
function(res) {
                        console.log("Response from the authorize call:")
                console.log(res)
```

The console.log(res) returns the following:

```
approved: true
​
authorization_token: "sometoken"
​
finalize_required: false
​
show_form: true
```

I want to use the authorization_token to send a POST request I have tried the following:

```
            function(res) {
                        console.log("Response from the authorize call:")
                console.log(res)
          

        
         var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
myHeaders.append("Authorization", "Basic mypw-usn");

var raw = JSON.stringify({
  "intent": "buy",
  "purchase_country": "GB",
  "purchase_currency": "GBP",
  "locale": "en-GB",
  "order_amount": 10,
  "order_tax_amount": 0,
    "order_lines": [{
    "type": "physical",
    "reference": "19-402",
    "name": "Battery Power Pack",
    "quantity": 1,
    "unit_price": 10,
    "tax_rate": 0,
    "total_amount": 10,
    "total_tax_amount": 0
  }],
  "merchant_urls": {
        "confirmation": "http://localhost:8888/jcart/mypage1.php",
        "authorization": "http://localhost:8888/jcart/mypag1e.php"
  }
});

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: raw,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("https://api.example//payments/v1/authorizations/res.authorization_token/order", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
                                }
```

The error I get is **TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.**
I think I am not showing the res.authorization_token correctly in the fetch url, however I do not know how to do this correctly.
Any help welcome

Comment: I guess this may be issue with CORS

Comment: @KhushbuChoksi thank you for your reply, however when I use POSTMAN to test it I just paste in the authorization token and this works fine I am have troubles I think with the authorization_token in the actual url i am not calling it properly I think

Comment: Does it throw the same error in postman without sending token?

Comment: @Amini no there it goes straight tough and I get the wanted result back

Comment: How are you adding it to the URL. This part is missing in your code snippet. Are you using string interpolation?

Comment: Are you sending the token in headers correctly?

Comment: @display-name Thank you for looking I am sending the the url as follows: fetch("https://api.playground.klarna.com//payments/v1/authorizations/res.authorization_token/order", requestOptions), I am almost sure it is the res.authorization_token but I dont know how I should put it in the URL

Comment: @Amini the headers are send and teast like this in postman and that seems to work

Comment: My first thought was that your token needs to be url encoded before you add it to the URL.